# pip doesn't grab latest version of tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Using 'pip install tweepy' I get version 1.7.1 of tweepy which is quite old and certainly doesn't support oauth.

Has a new version of the package not been published?

It's still under active development.  Do I need pull the source from GIT?  I'm just surprised there isn't a newer package.  Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.7.1 is the latest version on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy/), and the last tag listed in on [github](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/tree/1.7.1).  I'd say pip is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: I'm not implying pip isn't working correctly.  I'm just surprised how out-of-date the package is.  I wanted to know why the latest tweepy hasn't been distributed, or if I should be looking elsewhere for the distribution.  For now I've just checked the source from github.

Comment: @lostdorje, but the package isn't out-of-date.  There has been recent activivity, but none of the authors have created a new release.  If you are wondering why they haven't released anything since May of 2010, I'd suggest you contact one of the authors.

Comment: It's a fair point Adam.  Thanks.  I'm just new to the Python dev environment and wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything.